# VBA text file to excel by text file column numbers

Tags: excel, vba

I need find a way to import a text file to excel. I would like to import it by specific column numbers within the text file. (ex. COL 1-4 in A:A, COL 6-9 in B:B...etc) see text file clip below. Not very proficient with VBA so bear with me. Thank you in advance

from this:
[original text file snip](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6fWUs.png)

to this:
[desired excel sheet snip](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VMc0l.png)

This is what im starting with.

```
Dim fd As FileDialog
Set fd = Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogOpen)
Dim vrtSelectedItem As Variant

With fd
If .Show = -1 Then
    For Each vrtSelectedItem In .SelectedItems
        SelectedFile = vrtSelectedItem
    Next vrtSelectedItem
        mycancel = 2
Else
    mycancel = 1
End If
End With
Set fd = Nothing
sh_(1).Select

outputfile = "TEXT;" & SelectedFile

With ActiveSheet.QueryTables.Add( _
    Connection:=outputfile, _
    Destination:=Range("A2"))
    .Name = "text reader"
    .FieldNames = True
    .RowNumbers = False
    .FillAdjacentFormulas = False
    .PreserveFormatting = True
    .RefreshOnFileOpen = False
    .RefreshStyle = xlInsertDeleteCells
    .SavePassword = False
    .SaveData = True
    .AdjustColumnWidth = True
    .RefreshPeriod = 0
    .TextFilePromptOnRefresh = False
    .TextFilePlatform = 437
    .TextFileStartRow = 1
    .TextFileParseType = xlDelimited
    .TextFileTextQualifier = xlTextQualifierDoubleQuote
    .TextFileConsecutiveDelimiter = True
    .TextFileTabDelimiter = True
    .TextFileSemicolonDelimiter = False
    .TextFileCommaDelimiter = True
    .TextFileSpaceDelimiter = True
    .TextFileColumnDataTypes = Array(1, 1, 1)
    .TextFileTrailingMinusNumbers = True
    .Refresh BackgroundQuery:=False
End With
```

Comment: **What are the errors**?
Read Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example:
**https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve**

Comment: Do you have any sort of specification for the widths of each column?

Comment: **1:** I don't understand your specification: *`COL 1-4` in `A:A`, `COL 6-9` in `B:B`.* Your text file looks like it **might** be a tab delimited file, and your Excel snip looks like you just split it on the tab delimiter. I need more information.

Comment: My apologies for not being more specific. 

Columns widths do not matter as this data will be used to populate other sheets.

What I am looking for is all the characters in cloumns 1-4 from the text file to be populated in column A in excel and so on. I tried using the space delimiter but that splits it into too many separate columns. Not sure if there is a way to specify which columns from the text file get populated where.

Comment: Is there no specific delimiter that you can use?  Or is this a fixed width type of file?  Your macro indicates `.TextFileParseType = xlDelimited` but maybe that's not really the case?

Comment: When I change "TextFileSpaceDelimiter = False" and leave "TextFileTabDelimiter = True" it will populate each row from the text file in to Column A within excel. The file is fixed width

Comment: So then parse it as a fixed width file.  `DataType:=xlFixedWidth` and used the `FieldInfo` parameter to define your column widths (and data types).  See [MS documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.range.texttocolumns)

Comment: Does the file have a header line? How many lines of data typically thousands or hundreds of thousand?

Comment: There is no header line and the file is about 25,000 to 30,000 lines